# Create function is not working while using Django-crispy-forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I have a product model in my application, I have createded a forms.py file as well as a view function for it to create an object in it. I am then using it in my templates. after filling all the field and press submit, the page only reloads and the product object is not created.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class AddProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def Addproduct(request):

    form = AddProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Products Added Successfully")
            return redirect('product')

    context = {"form":form}

    return render(request, "core/addproduct.html", context)
```

addproduct.html

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
    {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
    {{ form.price|as_crispy_field }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
    {{ form.quantity|as_crispy_field }}
  </div>
</div>
{{ form.description|as_crispy_field }}
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
    {{ form.image|as_crispy_field }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
    {{ form.user|as_crispy_field }}
  </div>
</div>
<button class="au-btn au-btn--block au-btn--green m-b-20" type="submit">Add Product</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try `print(form.errors)` before rendering the template what output do you get? Most likely your form inputs are invalid in some way.

Comment: When dealing with files in a form, you should add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form tag in the HTML.

Comment: thanks Sir, it solved my issue, but why didn't even send a error so i could have seen it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
      {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0">
      {{ form.price|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="au-btn au-btn--block au-btn--green m-b-20" type="submit">Add Product</button>
</form>
```